# install imagemagick and PECL/imagick on XAMPP on windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, imagemagick, imagick

i'm trying to install imagemagick under windows with XAMPP and PHP 5.6.3

i have download and installed imagemagick ( ImageMagick-6.9.1-0-Q16-x64-dll.exe ) yet. In command window (cmd) i try to use convert ecc... and work correctly (then PATH is correct).

Next i download DLL from PECL/package/imagick in version 3.2.0b2 x64 TS for php 5.6 ( http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.2.0b2/php_imagick-3.2.0b2-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip )

i have set php.ini for load extension (retrive in before zip package and copyi it in c:\xampp\php\ext\ folder), i have copy all CORE_RL_*.DLL (retrive in before zip package) in c:\xampp\apache\bin\

restart PC and resstat apache/php server.
When apache/php start i have 2 warning msgbox (i think one for each PID(s) port 80 and port 443 ) than explain: "PHP Startup:" and i can press only ok.

in Xampp control panel Apache module and Mysql module are green but if i visited phpinfo.php i don't see imagemagick or imagick extension!

what's wrong???
what can i do it?

help me please

Answer (score 0):

Include the extension in php.ini file if not done.

```
extension=php_imagick.dll
```

And restart apache.

Comment: i just do it, but nothing

Comment: You dont have to create folder in php ext. Just paste all in c:\xampp\php\ext\

Comment: Also please check you have 64bit or 32bit windows.

Comment: i try with bot version (32 x86 e 64bit) but nothing, when start load libraries and the mex is show :(

Comment: Okay, I think you should start from scratch again with this tutorial http://www.kobashicomputing.com/installing-imagemagick-with-php-and-windows

Comment: Try installing xampp from fresh as you have done many changes and then follow this tutorial. I've installed imagick through this yesterday only. Download imagick from this link http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php

Comment: Thank you tiGer, as soon possible i try your tutorial link, my installation is clean, i have installed xampp on Virtual Machines

Comment: Great.. If you get into any problem then let me know if i can help.

Comment: i try your linked tutorial but when i start apache an error VCOMP110.DLL is missing. I try to reinstall Visual C++ Redistributable Packages any version 32 64 bit from 2008 to 2013 but nothing, always this error

Comment: i found it on my computer and i copy it on c:\ImageMagick with other dll files, than apache start with my first message "PHP startup", but nothing about imagick in php_info()

Comment: Check your php version and windows bit(32/64) and download imagick accordingly from above link..

Comment: Then unzip it in php/ext without creating any folder.

Comment: i follow your istructions but nothing, i try it all for x86 and for x64, i try to remove and reinstall all but every time i have this error

Comment: Give a try to download this http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.1.2/php_imagick-3.1.2-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip   and extract in php/ext

Comment: And use this  http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.6.5-10-Q16-windows-dll.exe  as imagemagic installation

Comment: with the first link from windows.php.net i have always this error:
http://picpaste.com/Cattura.PNG

with second link i have this warning
http://picpaste.com/Cattura2-TfzoU46g.PNG

Comment: Whats your xampp version?

Comment: last version, any package will be new download more and more time...it's all last version, or your version INDICATE by you in tutorial.